# Complex integral with poles on the curve

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

> Evaluate $\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^5 -32} dz$

Honestly, I have no idea how to proceed. My professor talked about integral with poles in the interior of the curves so that case was simple. I have never seen this type of integral. Can someone show me how can I proceed? Thanks before!

Comment: That integral doesn't make sense, precisely because there are poles on the curve.

Comment: You'd better check with your professor about whether he/she really intended to put any (all) of the poles on the curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^5 -32} dz$$ diverges.

What is well-defined, because $2 e^{2i\pi n/5} $ are simple poles, is $$PV(\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^5 -32} dz)$$
(principal value)

Then the theorem is that it is $$=\frac12(\int_{|z|=2+\epsilon}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^5 -32} dz+\int_{|z|=2-\epsilon}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^5 -32} dz)$$
to which we can apply the residue theorem.